# How to write excel using Apache POI with TestNG dataProvider

Tags: java, excel, apache, selenium, testng-dataprovider

I am working with hybrid framework, in these for writing an excel sheet I am using Apache-poi library by data provider.

I want my code in these way that by using it I can read and write my excel sheet in which test cases has been written and according to that cases it set their status.

Currently when I am executing my code it skipped the login method. Actually I am beginner in it and try to using it for read and write the excel, can anyone please help me to resolved the problem?

```
public class HybridExecuteTest {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\abc\\setup\\FFinstalled\\firefox.exe";
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFCell Cell;
    private static XSSFRow Row;
    WebDriver webdriver = null;

    @Test(dataProvider = "hybridData")
    public void testLogin(String testcaseName, String keyword,
            String objectName, String objectType, String value)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (testcaseName != null && testcaseName.length() != 0) {
            // webdriver=new FirefoxDriver();
            File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
            FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
            webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        }
        ReadObject object = new ReadObject();
        Properties allObjects = object.getObjectRepository();
        UIOperation operation = new UIOperation(webdriver);
        // Call perform function to perform operation on UI
        operation.perform(allObjects, keyword, objectName, objectType, value);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "hybridData")

    // This method is to set the File path and to open the Excel file, Pass Excel Path and Sheetname as Arguments to this method
        public Object[][] setExcelFile(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName) throws Exception {
        Object object[][] = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            // Open the Excel file
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Access the required test data sheet
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        } catch (Exception e) {throw (e);}
        return object;
    }
    // This method is to read the test data from the Excel cell, in this we are passing parameters as Row num and Col num
    public String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {
        try {
            Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
            return CellData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
    // This method is to write in the Excel cell, Row num and Col num are the parameters
    public String setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum,String filePath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        try {
            Row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
            Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (Cell == null) {
                Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);
                Cell.setCellValue(Result);
            } else {
                Cell.setCellValue(Result);
            }
            // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name
            File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            // Open the Excel file
            FileOutputStream ExcelFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ExcelWBook.write(ExcelFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```
SKIPPED: testLogin
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Some DataProvider public java.lang.Object[][] testCases.HybridExecuteTest.setExcelFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception parameters unresolved:  at 1 type class java.lang.String
 at 2 type class java.lang.String
 at 3 type class java.lang.String
```

**Note: I have go through the tutorial of Apache poi and normally I understand how to write but in framework I am stuck. Please help in these.**

Comment: This might be helpful: http://learn-automation.com/readwrite-excel-files-in-selenium/

Comment: @mfulton26 Can you please give the solution witjh above code which i have used with data provider. Because I have already given a note that I have go through all the tutorials.

Comment: you can also use one of available [data provider extension for TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension)

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to pass parameters to dataprovider, this is not supported.declare String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName as class level variables and then access them from the method.

```
String filePath="something"; String fileName="something"; String sheetName ="something";

 @DataProvider(name = "hybridData")
public Object[][] setExcelFile() throws Exception {
        Object object[][] = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            // Open the Excel file
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Access the required test data sheet
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        } catch (Exception e) {throw (e);}
        return object;
    }
```

Another problem that you will face is that you are not assigning anything to object[][] before returning it.